# Python - filename named after the content of a variable: IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory:

Tags: python, python-2.7, io

I have a problem with my code. Basically what I want to do is naming the .txt file after a string associated with a variable.

If I use a "static" name it works:

```
output_txt = open("filename.txt", "w")
output_txt.close()
```

If I instead get the text from the content of a variable, it doesn't work:

```
output_txt = open("%s.txt" % var.my_variable, "w")
output_txt.close()
```

`IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: "content of my_variable"`

my_variable is imported from a separate module and it's the result of a `raw_input`

Thanks.

Comment: what is `var.my_variable`?

Comment: I checked your code and it works well on my computer, it's probably an unescaped character (like a slash) that's messing with your code

Comment: @mittelmania Yes I suppose it is a slash. The var.my_variable has a fixed prefix. Variable is create in this way: my_variable = ("http://" + raw_input)
How do I escape the // when want to take the content of the variable as a string?

Comment: You cannot use `/` in a file name

Comment: @mittelmania I mean, I must escape the // but still they must be used correctly in my_variable as it's the prefix for a website. 
So I'll do like this instead. I use two variables: one "A" just containing http://.... and the other "B" the raw_input (i.e. name of the website). Then var.my_variable would be A+B so that it can be passed to urllib2.urlopen() while output_txt = open("%s.txt" % var.B + ".txt", w)
It seems working.

Comment: yes it  will work once you don't use `http://` as part of a filename

Comment: @Padraic Cunningham it seems I solved as I described above. Yet I don't think the code written like that it's elegant but at least it's working...

Comment: You could use var.my_variable.strip("http://")

Comment: @Padraic Cunningham this is more elegant, thank you. However in this way it strips everything contained in .strip("http://") from the filename. http://www.foowebsite.net would result in a filename www.foowebsite.ne (the "t" is stripped).

Comment: @Padraic Cunningham I solved using .lstrip() instead of .strip()

Answer (score 0):

I'll bet you have some directory structure in your variable.  If there are forward slashes in the path to the filename and the directory doesn't exist, you will get the error you referenced.  You can parse the input and check for the existence of the directory and possibly create it if it doesn't exist.